# Directives Angular 4 with JQuery Library does not work

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I use a JQuery Library (iCheck) and I want to do a directive for use it in my html component but it does not work ..
My code :
Directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[icheck]'
})

export class IcheckDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
      radioClass: 'iradio_minimal'});
    }
}
```

xxx.component.html

```
<label class="radio">
       <input type="radio" icheck name="filter" value="OF"> Other           </label>
```

IE : **icheck** is the selector name in my directive.
I Use Angular 4.

Comment: Try to follow the steps in this article: https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc

Comment: Thxx so much for this link ... But I dont see where he uses it in a html component like me .. I want use it in my html

Comment: The way you have setup is correct. What error are you getting?

Comment: I haven't error .. Its just the directive is not recognized in my component html .. I want to get something like http://icheck.fronteed.com/ in my button radio and checkBox